# How to create PDF using XSLT and Java and not XSLFO?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Can a PDF document be created using XSLT and Java without using XSLFO?

The reason why I ask is that I may have an xml document and need to use XSL to create PDF.  I may not have XSLFO document.

If not, how to convert XML into XSLFO document using Java?

Is it possible to create xslfo document directly with java instead of creating xml document?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to transform XSL-FO to PDF documents.
You can transform an XML document into XSL-FO using XSLT.

If you don't want to use XSLFO, it is possible to generate a PDF using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) but not from XML, or you will have to add logic to your program so that it knows how to parse the XML and how it should be rendered in the PDF.

Or you could translate your XML to HTML using XSLT and then use a library like [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) to generate the equivalent PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other intermediate formats that you can use on your way to generating PDF, but since you don't say why you don't like XSL-FO it's not clear whether you will like any other route any better.

Equally, an XSL-FO document is just an XML document and you can create it any way you like. XSLT is conventional and convenient but not the only way to do it. But since you don't say why you want a different solution, it's impossible to advise you.